# android application stopped unexpectedly emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Couldn't able to find the error. Logcat Provided

```
03-22 00:08:15.677: E/dalvikvm(275): Could not find class 'net.sourceforge.jeval.Evaluator', referenced from method com.math.Mainactivitycalculator.onCreate
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sourceforge.jeval.Evaluator 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at com.dbl.dothemath.Mainactivitycalculator.onCreate(Mainactivitycalculator.java:76) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
03-22 00:08:15.927: E/AndroidRuntime(275): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post related codes and edit your post..use code sample or press CTRL+K

Comment: Seems like the jar containing `net.sourceforge.jeval.Evaluator` is missing from your project libs.

Comment: Its there in the lib.

Comment: Not able too add the code...basically I m developing an app which will

Comment: show the graph of the equation entered by the user...\

Answer (score -2):

mathematical Expression involving numbers.
 Numbers are treated as doubles, so resulting numbers will contain at least one decimal place.
  string String can also be added together, compared, etc...
    Boolean Expression that evaluate to true (1.0) and false (0.0).
    functional Custom functions can be created or there are many Math and String functions that JEval supplies with this class.

Comment: i try your problem solve... you did not show your Code... so i just guest may be this problem..... Understand.....!!!